# Do I need to config ConvertView properties if it is not null?

Tags: android, android-adapter

In a custom `adapter`, how to know weither I need to reconfig the `convertView` or not?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = (ImageView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.avatar, parent, false);

        // Should this 2 lines of code be here ?
        User user = mUserList.getUserAt(position);
        user.setAvatar(imageView);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    // or here ?
    User user = mUserList.getUserAt(position);
    user.setAvatar(imageView);

    return imageView;
}
```

I would think that if it is recycled, I would not need to reset the user's avatar but I often see the configuration happening outside of the `if` block. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always configure the view outside of `if` block. This convertView that you get in the getView method might (and most probably will) be set up for another user by some previous call to getView because of ListView's policy to reuse item views when they go offscreen. If you do not set up a proper avatar you will have wrong one for this item. Of course you won't need to reset properties that are independent of the concrete position like background.

For example [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) [separates getView](http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#237) into two parts: newView, that performs inflate and (mostly) position-independent setup and bindView that assigns actual position-dependent data.

It may also happen that you will get exactly the same view that you used for this position earlier. Of course you can avoid resetting a view in this case, but you need to check if data in this view are valid. Setting and then checking View's [tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) comes to my mind as a most obvious solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is not truly recycled, it just means that you need to fill a "recycled" view with new data according to the its new position. If you don't do it this row will be filled with old data that shouln't be visible on the screen anymore since you scrolled away its position.

So in short you have to reconfigure view with fresh data each time getView() called (outside of `if` block in your code).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is only with the understanding of listview.

So here I'll make you clear **how it works??**

Let's say listview has to contain **20 items** but your current screen can accommodate(show on screen) only **8 items**(list items, in your case imageview).

When the listview tried to get items for `1----8th` it will return you `convertView` as `null` because **no recycling of objects** happened yet.

but, when you try to scroll, in our case(**scroll up!**).

```
the 1st element of the list will be recycled when go out of screen, and will be supplied as convertView for 9th item.
```

In this way listview has to manage only 8th(in our case) to show any number of items.

The opposite will happen if we will scroll down wards.

**So, on the basis of convert view (null or not) you have to design your logic either to create and fill or to fill.**

Hope this will help you.